# Generate valid words from string

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Due to some technical problem all the spaces in all sentences are removed. (except fullstops)

```
mystring='thisisonlyatest. andhereisanothersentense'
```

Is there any way in python to get the readable output like this...

> "this is only a test. and here is another sentense."

Comment: If you have a list of valid words, you can get all the prefixes, check whether they are a valid word, and recursively repeat with the rest of the sentence. Use memoization to provent redundant computations on same suffixes. This will give you a list of valid (but possibly non-sensical) ways to split the sentence into words.

Comment: I do not have a list of valid words. This is usual english text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of valid common words (can be found on the internet for different languages), you can get all the prefixes, check whether they are a valid word, and recursively repeat with the rest of the sentence. Use memoization to prevent redundant computations on same suffixes.

Here is an example in Python. The `lru_cache` annotation adds memoization to the function so that the sentence for each suffix is calculated only once, independently of how the first part has been split. Note that `words` is a `set` for O(1) lookup. A [Prefix-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would work very well, too.

```py
words = {"this", "his", "is", "only", "a", "at", "ate", "test", 
         "and", "here", "her", "is", "an", "other", "another",
         "sent", "sentense", "tense", "and", "thousands", "more"}
max_len = max(map(len, words))

import functools
functools.lru_cache(None)
def find_sentences(text):
    if len(text) == 0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(min(max_len, len(text)) + 1):
            prefix, suffix = text[:i], text[i:]
            if prefix in words:
                for rest in find_sentences(suffix):
                    yield [prefix] + rest

mystring = 'thisisonlyatest. andhereisanothersentense'
for text in mystring.split(". "):
    print(repr(text))
    for sentence in find_sentences(text):
        print(sentence)
```

This will give you a list of valid (but possibly non-sensical) ways to split the sentence into words. Those may be few enough so you an pick the right one by hand; otherwise you might have to add another post-processing step, e.g. using Part of Speech analysis with a proper NLP framework.